# Где допущена ошибка в WHILE цикле?

Tags: php, while

Есть 2 запроса. Один по определенному пользователю, а другой по целому массиву пользователей. Первый пример кода который приведу, он по 1 пользователю и работает нормально. То есть, считает и суммирует все его вещи. А второй код практически тоже самое, не считает. Выводит всего 1 вещь и её стоимость.

```
////////СЧИТАЕМ СКОЛЬКО ДЕНЕГ ВЕЩАМИ У КАЖДОГО ИГРОКА!
$totalitemoney = 0;
$itemid = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM `items` LEFT OUTER JOIN `items_info` ON `items`.`item_id` = `items_info`.`id` WHERE `user_id`=36454");
while($moneyitemuser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemid)){

$totalitemoney = $totalitemoney + $moneyitemuser[price];

}
```

А вот нерабочий пример.

```
$totalmoneytopuser = 0;
while($usersall = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userall)){

if ($usersall[ban_chat] == 0) {$usersban='<span class="label label-success  label-pill">NO</span>';}    
if ($usersall[ban_chat] == 1) {$usersban='<span class="label label- label-pill">YES</span>';}

$topusersitemss = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM `items` LEFT OUTER JOIN `items_info` ON `items`.`item_id` = `items_info`.`id` WHERE `user_id`='$usersall[id]'"); 
$topusersitems = mysqli_fetch_assoc($topusersitemss);

$totalmoneytopuser = $totalmoneytopuser + $topusersitems[price];

echo "
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$usersall[id]</td>
                      <td><img src='$usersall[avatar]' alt='user' width='30'>    <a href='./dice.php?tag=$usersall[id]'>$usersall[username]</a></td>
                      <td>$usersall[money]</td>
                      <td>$totalmoneytopuser</td>
                      <td>$usersall[created_at]</td>
                      <td>$usersban</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
";
}
```

$totalmoneytopuser не суммирует все вещи по каждому игроку. 
Почему?

Comment: А вы заметили, что в первом случае вы в цикле перебираете все строки, а во втором выбираете только одну строку. Но на самом деле это все вообще не нужно. Вместо цикла в первом примере достаточно модифицировать sql-запрос примерно на `SELECT sum(price) as price FROM items LEFT OUTER JOIN items_info ON items.item_id = items_info.id WHERE user_id=36454`. Он получит готовую сумму, что гораздо быстрее, чем вытягивать все строки данных и считать в php

Comment: А во втором случае, учитывая что вы и так находитесь в цикле чтения пользователей вам надо объединить два запроса (по пользователям, который вы не показали и внутренний) примерно в `SELECT users.id, users.name, ..., sum(price) as price FROM users JOIN items  ON ... LEFT OUTER JOIN items_info ON items.item_id = items_info.id GROUP BY users.id, users.name, ...` И он вам даст просто список полльзователей по одной строке и сразу в этой же строке готовую сумму. Так что учите SQL, его знание позволит ускорить как свою работу, так как заменяет десятки строк php-кода, так и скорость работы приложения

Comment: @Mike ох, просто огромнейшее спасибо, что подсказали как правильно. Попробовал, так действительно намного быстрее и короче. Спасибо.